# PowerShell sends empty JSON payload

Tags: json, azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-service-principal

I am calling GraphAPI to update keycredentials for a service principal. I create the JSON payload through combining data from a GET call and a custom JSON object.

I have a variable that is not empty, but when I make an API call I get an "empty payload" error. Why is my `$body` variable considered empty when it clearly isn't?

Below is the information on how I populate this variable.

**Information**

Here is the script:

```
. .\GetSecretToken.ps1
. .\pull_cert_data.ps1

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}"  -Method Get -Headers $Header

$current_keys = $response.keycredentials

$key_credentials = $current_keys + $new_KeyCredentials

$key_credentials | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File .\checkkeys.txt


$hash_body = 
    @{"keyCredentials" = $key_credentials
    "passwordCredentials" = $password_credentials}

$body = $hash_body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
$body | out-file .\checkvalue.txt
$body

$json = $body


$update_cert = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}" -Method Patch -Headers $Header -Body $json
```

If I use the `$body` variable in the `$update_cert` call, I get an empty payload error:

```
    {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Empty Payload. JSON content | expected."
```

However, if I use the `$json` variable, which just equals the `$body` variable, my call is successful. It will also print the contents of the `$body` variable in the terminal, so I know it isn't empty. The script creates two files that were originally done to make sure the JSON formatting was correct.

Here is the output of the `$body` variable:

```
{
  "keyCredentials": [
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": "<HASH_OF_THUMBPRINT>",
      "displayName": "<CN>",
      "endDateTime": "<EXPIRY_DATE>",
      "key": null <EXISTING_CERT>,
      "keyId": "<GUID>",
      "startDateTime": "<START_DATE>",
      "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
      "usage": "Verify"
    },
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": "<HASH_OF_THUMBPRINT>",
      "displayName": "<CN>",
      "endDateTime": "<EXPIRY_DATE>",
      "key": null <EXISTING_CERT>,
      "keyId": "<GUID>",
      "startDateTime": "<START_DATE>",
      "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
      "usage": "Sign"
    },
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": "<HASH_OF_THUMBPRINT>",
      "displayName": "<CN>",
      "endDateTime": "<EXPIRY_DATE>",
      "key": null <EXISTING_CERT>,
      "keyId": "<GUID>",
      "startDateTime": "<START_DATE>",
      "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
      "usage": "Verify"
    },
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": "<HASH_OF_THUMBPRINT>",
      "displayName": "<CN>",
      "endDateTime": "<EXPIRY_DATE>",
      "key": null <EXISTING_CERT>,
      "keyId": "<GUID>",
      "startDateTime": "<START_DATE>",
      "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
      "usage": "Sign"
    },
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": "<HASH_OF_THUMBPRINT>",
      "endDateTime": "<EXPIRY_DATE>",
      "type": "X509CertandPassword",
      "key": "<NEWCERT-PrivateKey>",
      "displayName": "<CN>",
      "startDateTime": "<START_DATE>",
      "keyId": "<GUID>",
      "usage": "Sign"
    },
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": "<HASH_OF_THUMBPRINT>",
      "endDateTime": "<EXPIRY_DATE>",
      "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
      "key": "<NEWCERT-PublicKey>",
      "displayName": "<CN>",
      "startDateTime": "<START_DATE>",
      "keyId": "<GUID>",
      "usage": "Verify"
    }
  ],
  "passwordCredentials": [
    {
      "endDateTime": "<EXPIRY_DATE>",
      "secretText": "<PASSPHRASE_FOR_NEW_CERT>",
      "startDateTime": "<START_DATE>",
      "keyId": "<KEY_ID_OF_PRIVATE_KEY>",
      "customKeyIdentifier": "<HASH_OF_THUMBPRINT_OF_NEW_CERT>"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note**: The `$new_keyCredentials` and `$password_credentials` variables are arrays that contain the hashtables of the new keycredentials and password credentials of those keys and are imported from the `pull_cert_date.ps1` script.  The `$Header` is coming from `GetSecretToken.ps1` script.

Comment: When API return `Bad Request` means your request does not met the expected format, meaning it could be simple as an array inside the JSON instead of a variable. You should try to break it down to a literally JSON format input like so `$json=@"{value.."@` and if that works then try to recreate that specific format with `convertto-json` , then you would be able to identify where the issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

> PowerShell sends empty JSON payload

This error states that the PowerShell that the command is wanting the Json and the input provided is empty.

I have reproduced your requirement in my environment, and I have faced similar issue as you.
So, when I displayed the body i got the below as output:

[image]

And if I send this as the Json in invoke command, I get similar error as you got.

Then I used `ConvertTo-Json` and I got expected results as below:

[image]

Here what I observed is when I converted \n are added and it worked as expected.

References:

- ["Empty Payload. JSON content expected" when uploading an item to OneDrive from a URL · Issue #745 · OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/745)